# How to test if a variable exists or if it has a certain value

Tags: xpath-2.0

I am working on a "standalone" xpath parser (not integrated into XSLT). Does the spec define how to check if a variable exists?

Pseudo code:

```
Host language: if condition then set variable "foo" to "bar"

...

XPath: if $foo='bar' then ...
```

Now the variable `$foo` can be defined or not, depending on *condition* above. What would be the correct behavior of an XPath implementation?

1. raise a runtime error if condition is false and thus `$foo` is not defined?
2. raise a runtime/compile time error because it *could*  be undefined?
3. I assume there is no default value (such as "nil") for a non existing variable.
4. ...?

It would be great to have a pointer to the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical way is to raise err:XPDY0002 if the variable has not been assigned a value. But since I am allowed:

> If an expression can validly return a value or raise a dynamic error, the implementation may choose to return the value or raise the dynamic error.

I chose to go for an empty string in my implementation as a default value for a variable and give a warning instead.

The answer to my own is most likely (after reading the spec again) "it's implementation defined".

Comment: But that part only refers to situations like `false and $missing` where the result is independent of the value of the erroneous expression, not about inventing new values.

Comment: I will implement it anyway and see what problems arise in day to day use. Then I'll rethink the code handling. IMO the spec is not clear at that point. When I say for example `if $missing = 'hello'` then it would not harm if I set `$missing` to the empty string as a default. Obviously the case "if variable is bound to the empty string then ..."  will be broken, but I will have to live with that case.

Comment: Well, perhaps the biggest problem you are going to have is, if someone wants to write `$i - 1`, forgets the spaces and writes `$i-1`

Answer (score 0):

The spec does not allow to change variables. (except ofc for variables defined for sub expressions like in for loops)

Therefore the list of variables existing at any point is known at compile time and it is a static error [err:XPST0008](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#ERRXPST0008) to use a not declared variable.

Comment: Variables can be set from outside (as in XSLT). Therefore I am having trouble defining the static context to raise the mentioned error. My language is tree like as XSLT.

Comment: But then they are set before the xpath is compiled. And it would not be a standalone implementation.

Comment: The XPath are embedded in a host language, right. But the variables are not necessarily set before the xpath is executed (see the edited question).

Comment: But in XPath the variables cannot change during the execution. If they can, it is not XPath and it does not matter what the spec says

Comment: Even in XSLT the variables change during execution.

Comment: I have a host language, comparable to XSLT. The difference to XSLT is that my control flow is more procedural than XSLT, therefore the host language has not necessarily set a variable.

Comment: @topskip, Your statement: "Even in XSLT the variables change during execution." is not true. The value of an `xsl:variable`, once this variable is defined, cannot be changed.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, sure, but during the next run of the template/... it might be a different value. The current topic is about statical analysis and it is much easier in XSLT than in my language.

Comment: @topskip, Re: "during the next run of the template/... it might be a different value". Again incorrect: even if they have the same name, variables that live in different executions of a template, are completely different -- they aren't "the same variable".

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev what I mean, and you know it, is that the contents of what is accessed by `$foobar`is different. And that is what my original question is about.

Comment: @topskip, You need use the accepted, normative terminology, if you want to have a chance for your questions being understood.